# Swift: Arrows over keyboard to navigate between label in a Swift view

Tags: xcode, swift

When a user interact with text fields in a HTML form, a right and left arrows appear over the keyboard to navigate between the text fields.

I was wondering if there was settings available to make these arrows appear as well when the user navigate between labels in a view.

Comment: Here you go:  [Arrow](http://i57.tinypic.com/mwzakh.jpg). This is the arrows appearing when filling out a web form.